# how return picture after after redraw with Bitmap

Tags: java, android, image, bitmapimage

Help me realized some logic.
I have a picture which redrawing by:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        BitmapDrawable mydrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap b = mydrawable.getBitmap();
        b = doHighlightImage(b);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
});

public static Bitmap doHighlightImage(Bitmap src) {
    // создадим новый битмап, который станет итоговым
    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth() + 96,
            src.getHeight() + 96, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    // подключаем холст
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOut);
    // установим цвет по умолчанию
    canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

    // создадим размытие для прозрачности
    Paint ptBlur = new Paint();
    ptBlur.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, Blur.NORMAL));
    int[] offsetXY = new int[2];
    // получим прозрачный слепок из изображения
    Bitmap bmAlpha = src.extractAlpha(ptBlur, offsetXY);
    // готовимся к рисованию
    Paint ptAlphaColor = new Paint();
    ptAlphaColor.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    // закрашиваем цветом цветной слепок (bitmap)
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmAlpha, offsetXY[0], offsetXY[1], ptAlphaColor);
    // освобождаем ресурсы
    bmAlpha.recycle();

    // рисуем исходник
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

    // возвращаем финальный рисунок
    return bmOut;
}
```

But, after redrawing i must return the initial state of the picture. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by `must return the initial state of the picture`? Bitmap is immutable, so just keep a reference to whatever bitmap you need and don't worry about changing it - it's impossible.

Comment: i mean, method which cancel redraw i apply it for on click2
and after onclick(i make highlighting of picture) i make onclick2 redrawing canceling and i have picture size and colors was before

Comment: @DenysKarpov place somwhere in the class `Bitmap mOldBitmap;`, then `oldBitmap = b` in the `onClick` method before `b = doHighlightImage(b);`. After that just use the bitmap on cancel action